# Multiselect plugin

Tags: jquery

I wonder is there any kind of jQuery plugin to make multiselect look something similar to the attached image? I mean this clicking on options and buttons save/cancel.
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best MultiSelect I've used is here: http://loudev.com/.
I've used it in many different sites and applications. Lou actually keeps his GitHub current and responds to issues. There is some good support Q&A also.

Answer (score 1):

have a look of this http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget or this http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/ hope it helps you